# Python validation loop won't ask the same question if incorrect answer/string is placed

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an insurance program and in my program it asks you if you have any family history of Alzheimer's, Cancer, and/or, diabetes. If you have all three, you get 30 risk points, if you have none, you get 0 risk points. I am trying to validate the code by asking the same question if the person doesn't answer the question with a yes or no.

```py
# Calculate Family Disease Scores
    
diabetes = ''

while True:
   diabetes = input('\n Do you have a family history of Diabetes? (Answer yes or no)')

   if diabetes == 'y' or 'yes':
      diabetesScore = 10
      break
   elif diabetes == 'n' or 'no':
      diabetesScore = 0
      break
   else: 
      print('Please answer Yes or No')
      continue
   
cancer = ''

while True:
   cancer = input('\n Do you have a family history of cancer? (Answer yes or no)')

   if cancer == 'y' or 'yes':
      cancerScore = 10
      break
   elif cancer == 'n' or 'no':
      cancerScore = 0
      break
   else: 
      print('Please answer Yes or No')
      continue
   
alzheimers = ''

while True:
   alzheimers = input('\n Do you have a family history of alzheimers? (Answer yes or no)')

   if alzheimers == 'y' or 'yes':
      alzheimersScore = 10
      break
   elif alzheimers == 'n' or 'no':
      alzheimersScore = 0
      break
   else: 
      print('Please answer Yes or No')
      continue
```

Comment: This syntax is wrong: `if diabetes == 'y' or 'yes':`.  That expression will always be `True`.  What you want is `if diabetes in ('yes', 'no'):`. You don't need the `continue`.

Comment: @CryptoFool how would I format that? Sorry I'm very new to python so unsure of how I would format that.

Comment: Like I said in my initial comment.